# Adding GUI and Functions to Android drawer Fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I apologise in advanced if this has been asked or is not worded correctly.

I have created an android app with 3 different activities, the buttons link up perfectly and what not, I have one of the activities opening a navigation drawer activity, I have changed nothing in this stock Navigation activity, it gives me 3 sections when I slide across, section 1, 2 and 3.

I have a text to speech activity which works perfectly, my question is how can I click on section 1 in the Navigation drawer and it will open the Text to speech activity or is this even possible,

I have searched the web for hours and cant seem to understand the difference with fragments and activities, I am new to android and really am sorry if my question is dumb im just getting really stressed over my project now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, but I think simple `Intent` is what you are looking for.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTextToSpeech.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This piece of code will work as it is, if you put it in an `Activity`.

In your case (if you have the basic structure generated by IDE) you should put it in the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)` function in the `MainActivity` class. You should run this code only if the position argument is equal 0, because you want to fire the code only when the first section is pressed.

---

On the side note, maybe it would be more profitable for you if you started with basic activities and layouts so you understand the fundamental structures of Android. Fragments, although in many cases very useful, probably aren't the best thing to start with.

If you don't plan on to create an application that displays differently on phones and tablets or different screen orientations etc, you probably don't even need Fragments. There are not so many cases where you actually have to use them. They give you an extra flexibility (that you probably don't need yet), in exchange for unnecessary complexity in code that you don't want.

I know that navigation drawer is cool, but it is not as easy as it seems and if I were you, I would start somewhere else :)

Comment: Thank you,  I'll take your advice and scrap the navigation drawer